# Filter NSSet with objects to get object with max property value

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, filtering

I have a NSSet of complex objects called `messages`. Every message has a property `dateCreated`.

I am simply trying to get the message with the max `dateCreated`in a efficient way.

I can still get the max date by using KVC:
`NSDate *d = [messages valueForKeyPath:@"@max.dateCreated"];`

I think its the wrong way to ask for the max value and than loop against the messages picking the correct one.

Maybe it helps that my objects are from Core Data? Any ideas?

Comment: If you are using core data, run a fetch request sorted by date created, and select the first item.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Core Data, you should run a fetch request, sort by date created, and return the first item. This code is untested, but it should go something like this:

```
- (MyEntity *)newestMyEntityInContext:(NSManagedObjectContext *)context
{
    NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"entity"];
    [request setSortDescriptors:@[[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"dateCreated"
                                                                ascending:NO]]];
    [request setFetchLimit:1];

    NSError *error = nil;
    NSArray *results = [context executeFetchRequest:request
                                              error:&error];

    if (!results) {
        NSLog(@"%@", error);
        return nil;
    }

    return results.count ? results[0] : nil;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I did not know, that I can use the context of a fetched object again. Great!

Answer (score 2):

Since you need to loop through the objects anyway, just use fast enumeration:

```
// Find the object with the maximum value for dateCreated
// Of course, replace both NSObject's with the appropriate class
NSObject *maxObject;
for (NSObject *object in messages)
{
    if ([object.dateCreated laterDate:maxObject.dateCreated]))
        maxObject = object;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In case you just have an NSSet and don't use CoreData, the following approach works:

```
NSSortDescriptor *dateDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"dateCreated" ascending:YES];
NSArray *sortDescriptors = @[ dateDescriptor ];
NSArray *sortedArray = [messages sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

if (sortedArray.count>0)
{
   id oldestMessage = [sortedArray firstObject];
   id newestMessage = [sortedArray lastObject];
}
```